# Xcode 11 Beta 7 crash when running on device but not in canvas or simulator

Tags: crash, swiftui, xcode11

I've run into a problem with Xcode crashing when trying to run my SwiftUI app on my iPhone XS Max. The crash only occurred after upgrading to the latest Xcode 11 Beta 7. Also, the app still runs without an issue in the canvas and with the iPhone Simulator. Below is the error code that I get, the app doesn't go past the launch screen when running on my device. My device is running iOS 13.1

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan inf]. Layer: >; sublayers = (); opaque = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; anchorPoint = CGPoint (0 0)>'"

Where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, noticed someone posted that it's not possible to run apps on devices with iOS 13.1 currently using the Beta 7 build.

Comment: FYI? I've had no issues running on my iOS 13.1 device with Xcode 7 - well, one. t broke my image selection. (Not my `UIImagePicker`, but pulling the image file out of the "hidden" file system. And that's happening in my `UIKit` apps also. My solution, almost complete, is to write my own image picker that uses `Photos` instead.)